# I am having issues running train.py and I am confused

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have run and successfully compiled all of the code off of this website:
[Medium article](https://medium.com/swlh/nvidia-jetson-nano-custom-object-detection-from-scratch-using-tensorflow-and-opencv-113fe4dba134)
I have gotten to the training point and go to run the command:

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco.config
```

Yet I get an error that it can't find train.py and I read that this is outdated and that I should run model_main.py and when I do that I get this error

> 2020-01-24 15:43:27.488352: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "model_main.py", line 24, in 
>       from object_detection import model_hparams
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'

I am on a windows 10 x64 machine with python 3.7. I have tried with my working directory outside of the models folder where object-detection is and directly inside the object-detection folder where all the files are. If anyone can help that would be amazing thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

Running tensorflow on windows is not easy, yet check instructions on https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2031

TLDR:

- Go to models/research directory
- Run following commands

  ```
   python setup.py build
   python setup.py install
  ```
- If you are using Anaconda, run these also in same directory

  ```
   conda develop .
   conda develop slim/
  ```